# Termination from academic program when I was unable to pay the fee and write the exam because i was being Covid +ve

Tags: contract-law, india, education

I'm a student of IIT Dhanbad from India, I was terminated from the academic program because I was unable to pay the fee and write the exam. The payment date was 1-7 April and the exam date was 19-24 April. Starting from April month my whole family and I was being COVID +ve. I was tested on 13 April and got Covid +ve my mother and father were in critical condition due to being COVID +ve. in that situation it was not possible to pay the fee and write the exam. I was requested to give a chance to pay the fee but they didn't reply. I had also request for make up exam but they said you are not applicable for it because you didn't pay the fee.
I want to know how can take legal action against them?

Answer (score 1):

### You can’t

I’m sorry to hear about your circumstances but they are, unfortunately, *yours*. The fact that you or a family member is sick or has otherwise suffered misadventure does not give you an excuse for avoiding your contractual obligations; in this case, to pay the fee by the due date. In fact, as I read it, the due date for payment had come and gone *before* you became ill.